# Script AppendRow at the top

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this little code to insert data from a form to a specific sheet.

```
function grabarEnSheets(e) {
  //Conectarse con sheets
  const libro=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SheetID")
  const hoja=libro.getSheetByName("Patrol-Logs")
  
  //Traer respuestas
  const respuestaEnviada=e.response;
  const respuestas=respuestaEnviada.getItemResponses();
  const Nombre = respuestas[0].getResponse();
  const Dia = respuestas[1].getResponse();
  const Tiempo = respuestas[2].getResponse();
  const Evidencia = respuestas[3].getResponse();
  const Traje = respuestas[4].getResponse();

  //Campos nuevos
  var fecha=new Date();

//Guardar respuestas en sheets
hoja.appendRow([fecha,Nombre,Tiempo,Dia,Evidencia,Traje])
}

function darPermisos(){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID")
  FormApp.getActiveForm();
}
```

And the appendRow adds the data at the bottom of the sheet.
So what I need is to append all entry data from the form and skip the first and second table.
[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I don't know how to make appendRow to start adding the data at the third file, and not at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I thought that you wanted to append a data row to the 3rd tab. For this, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Might my answer is out of the GAS, I suggest it would be better experience to not modify form submission sheet, create another sheet sort raw data by desc

Comment: You can do this if you add sorting by the `fecha` field after adding the data to the sheet `hoja.getRange('A3:F').sort({column: 1, ascending: false})` or if you replace your `hoja.appendRow` with `hoja.insertRowAfter(2); hoja.getRange('A3:F3').setValues([[fecha,Nombre,Tiempo,Dia,Evidencia,Traje]])` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following replying in the comment,

> I don't know how to make appendRow to start adding the data at the third file, and not at the bottom.

I thought that you might have wanted to append a data row to the 3rd tab on the Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
hoja.appendRow([fecha,Nombre,Tiempo,Dia,Evidencia,Traje])
```

#### To:

```
libro.getSheets()[2].appendRow([fecha,Nombre,Tiempo,Dia,Evidencia,Traje]);
```

- `libro.getSheets()[2]` means the 3rd tab on the active Spreadsheet.
- If you want to use `appendRow` to the specific sheet, you can also use the following script using the sheet name.

  ```
    libro.getSheetByName("###SheetName###").appendRow([fecha,Nombre,Tiempo,Dia,Evidencia,Traje]);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getSheets() of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you very much.